# Entering UIImagePickerController editing mode

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I use a `UIImagePickerController` (`photoPicker`) to take pictures with the camera, and edit those picture (`allowEditing = YES`). The user can switch between Camera and Library with a button in `photoPicker.view`, but I want to remove this button when `photoPicker` is in editing mode.

In `photoLibrarySourceType` the picker uses a push to show editing mode, so it works with this method:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (navigationController == photoPicker) {
        NSLog(@"navigation ");
        if ([navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController] == 1)
        {
            // If second UIViewController, set your overlay.
            NSLog(@"editing");
        }
    }
}
```

But in `cameraSourceType`, there is no navigation between camera and editing mode.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a little hack and it works for me. Am still a little new so please optimize at will as i couldn't find another way to do it.

The basic idea is to create an invisible button over the default camera button that performs a method that calls [uiimagepickercontroller takePicture]

here is my sample code

```
@implementation myViewController
{
    UIImagePickerController *myImagePickerController; 
    UIButton * fakeCameraButton;


}

- (IBAction)showImagePicker:(id)sender{

    // accessible camera validations implied
    myImagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    myImagePickerController.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;       
    myImagePickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;
    myImagePickerController.delegate=self;
    myImagePickerController.allowsEditing=YES; 

    CGFloat myViewHeight = 100; // you play around with the positions to get your desired frame size. This worked for me
    UIView * myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, myImagePickerController.view.frame.size.height - myViewheight, picker.view.frame.size.width, myViewheight)];

   fakeCameraButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myView.frame.size.width / 2 - 30, myView.frame.size.height/2-15, 60, 60)];// position it over the default camera button
   [fakeCameraButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cameraButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [fakeCameraButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   [myView addSubview:fakeCameraButton];
   myImagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = myView;
   [self presentViewController:myImagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];


}

-(void)cameraButtonPressed{

    // Make sure you check if camera is ready before this method. 
   [myImagePickerController takePicture];

    // you are in editing/preview mode here if allowsEditing = YES

    // you can remove all your custom overlay views by
    myImagePickerController.cameraOverlay = nil



}
```

Like i said before just make sure you check if camera is ready. You can find answers here on stackoverflow on how to do it.

This code may suck so editing or alternative solutions are welcomed.

I need dev buddy to help me learn more about ios dev and ask questions. anyone interested?